# How to assign an elastic ip to aws load bouncer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an issue that current registrar allow only ANAME reference, so I have a an Elastic ip for all my web settings. I would like to assign it to the load balancer and then load balancer will decide who is going to handle it.

I cannot find a way to create it with Route 53. I cannot add my route 53 domains to my registrar and would appreciate any advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't confuse your registrar with your DNS hosting provider.  They are often the same, out of convenience but not necessity.  The registrar does not control what kind of DNS records you can create.  That's the DNS hosting provider, which can be switched to Route 53 while keeping your current registrar if desired, by changing the authoritative name servers (with your registrar) to the ones found in your Route 53 hosted zone.

Comment: thank you, Mike. In my case they are the same - just a brief question - may my change in DNS records make mail services stop working?

That's a daily newspaper and their mail server is crucial for their work. This is it www.svet.com

Comment: If you copy the `MX` records and any related entries from your current DNS provider to Route 53, then they shouldn't.

Comment: Thx, so they have to point back to 1plus1 mx settings?

Comment: Well, it does not work this way, but this is probably registrar settings. But thank you though for your suggestion. I created now a powerful instance,  it handles everything but we need to switch from 1plus1 to AWS, then it will be easy. Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ANAME record to an A record that has the EIP of your Load Balancer.  You can set a high TTL, because "your" EIP won't change. You don't even need your web servers in DNS. Your Load Balancer should just have a list of their IPs.

It will look like this:

1) Client does a DNS lookup for foo.com

2) Client gets A record that has (E)IP of LB

3) Send request to LB's IP

4) LB distributes traffic to web servers

If your LB dies, spin up a new one and move the EIP to it.

Comment: Have you ever tried attaching an EIP to an ELB?  How is that done?

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention ELB, so I assumed you had a physical box for LB.  In that case you need to use ANAME to point to ELB. But your DNS provider *may not* be able to do that. If they can't help you, follow Matts' advice and move to R53.

Comment: I'm not the OP but I assumed "AWS load balancer" meant ELB, and as such, "How is that done?" was a bit of an unfair question on my part, since I knew it couldn't be done. :)

Comment: Thank you, guys. Sorry, for my "limitations", but 1plus1 registrar allows only ANAME ref, you can use CNAME, but in that case they stop all your mail services - which is not acceptable for me. You can safely create ANAME (though with IP4 and with IP6) then it changes only web requests. But I all that I have is 1 ip. I guess in this condition - the best strategy is to run 1 instance but get a powerful one. Am I right?

Comment: The `ANAME` you create should point to a hostname, not an IP address, and in the case of ELB, it would be the ELB hostname you would use as the target.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your registrar use Route 53 as its Nameserver. In Route 53 create a hosted zone and use an A record of type Alias and choose the Elastic Load Balancer Endpoint.

Comment: Thank you, Matt. Yes, I went to this point.... by the way, do you know if I change Nameservers on registrar side - does it influence mail services (MX)?

Comment: I believe it does. You will have to move all the MX records to the Route 53 hosted zone.